# Woodmart theme optimization

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization

I have a store website with a Woodmart theme. Which is in the field of selling decoration products. Each website product may have at least 10 to 20 images in the image gallery. Although I use lazy loading, the product pages of the site are slow due to the image gallery. The speed of all sections of the site is excellent, only the product pages are not displayed correctly due to the image gallery. Thanks to all the friends for their help if you have a similar experience.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you provide some code ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi kissu, i dont understand what do you mean about providing some code?

Comment: It's hard to help you without any visual concrete code to debug. "only the product pages are not displayed correctly due to the image gallery", alright, based on this one I'm not sure that anybody will be able to help you by saying: "Yep, this is the EXACT issue you do face right now, here is how to fix it".